# How to use a pp function (formatter -> 'a -> unit) as an arg to printf?

Tags: ocaml

I am using a 3rd party module which exposes a function:

```ml
val pp : Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit
```

Unfortunately it doesn't expose a `to_string` (or `show`) function.

I want to find a way to use the result of `pp` in a format string, something like:

```ml
let output = Format.sprintf "Result: %s" (SomeModule.pp fmt myval)
```

But `pp` writes to `fmt` and returns `unit` so of course this is not valid.

I can tell I need to somehow make a formatter to pass to `pp` that writes to a string buffer, that I can then get contents of as a string, which I can then pass as an arg to `sprintf`

The use of `pp` like functions for making types printable seems pretty ubiquitous in OCaml (e.g. [ppx_deriving show](https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving#plugin-show) generates them) so I feel like there should be a simple way to achieve this, but I'm currently missing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `asprintf` instead, it's possible to use the `%a` format specifier to pass two arguments, a printer function and the value to be printed, which will then be formatted accordingly and inserted in its place:

```
let output = Format.asprintf "Result: %a" SomeModule.pp myval
```

The reason `asprintf` has to be used instead of `sprintf` is that the latter specifies an "input source" (the second argument of the `format` type) of type `unit`, while the former uses a `formatter`. This is what's going to be passed to the printer.

It still alludes me why there's a need for `sprintf` though, rather than just having `asprintf`. Perhaps there's some performance-related reason for it, but my guess is that it's just an artifact of history.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! I had tried using `asprintf` and `%a` at some point but hadn't worked out the correct form of args to pass. I feel like the docs for `Format`/`Printf` could do a better job of illustrating the complicated anonymous type signatures of these methods with examples.